# How is Parameter implemented in PyTorch?

Tags: python, inheritance, pytorch

I'm trying to wrap my head around how Parameter (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/329a9a90c0a579a3c67370702454f254109f1c9c/torch/nn/parameter.py) is implemented in PyTorch.

I see that Parameter inherits Tensor, which allows you to perform tensor operations easily, e.g. if `p` is a Parameter, then you can simply call `p * 2` or `p.tanh()` without retrieving the underlying Tensor.

What confuses me is how Parameter stores its private variable `data`, as it seems to point to a nonexistent parent Tensor object.

Is it just a reference to `self`? Is it a Tensor wrapper around the child Parameter class? It is a property that does some magic to return the Tensor data?

Answer (score 0):

Many of the implementation details for PyTorch under the hood use C++ and PyObjects. You can see that the code you refer to, in `__new__` returns `torch.Tensor._make_subclass(cls, data, requires_grad)`. The implementation can be found in python_variable.cpp as `THPVariable_make_subclass` (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/bb6b157458a34d8b3499932035381fdb12683703/torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.cpp#L567).